# Ignore special Turkish characters when partial matching

Tags: r

Suppose that we have a "AMID DIMAD YUZBASIOGLU" string. What I want to do is to match possible strings such as "AMİD YÜZBAŞIOĞLU","AMID YÜZBAŞIOĞLU", "AMID DİMAD YÜZBAŞIOĞLU" with "AMID DIMAD YUZBASIOGLU" using grep function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `iconv(your_string, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')` to convert special characters to 'ASCII' and then use `grep`

```
> x <- "AMID DIMAD YUZBASIOGLU" 
> string <- c("AMİD YÜZBAŞIOĞLU","AMID YÜZBAŞIOĞLU","AMID DİMAD YÜZBAŞIOĞLU")
> y <- iconv(string, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
> grep(x, y)
[1] 3
```